# hide the rest of the list in css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Is is possible to hide the rest of the `list` example? I have 10 items in the `list` and I want to hide all of the list items after 4 `list`:

```
<ul>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>hide this list</li>
  <li>hide this list</li>
  <li>hide this list</li>
  <li>hide this list</li>
  <li>hide this list</li>
  <li>hide this list</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do with :nth-child...

```
li:nth-child(n+5) {
  display: none;
}
```

More here: http://nthmaster.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to modify the HTML code, you can add classes to the list items you wish to hide.

**Otherwise**, you can use this piece of CSS code:

```css
li:nth-child(n+5) {
    display: none;
}
```

This is a very generic selector though, so you may wish to scope it using classes or other more specific selectors.

Read more about [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) and [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type).

Comment: +1 I like the note about adding classes because this addresses issues in browsers that donot support the `:nth-child` selector

Answer (score 0):

You tagged it with jQuery so... How about [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)?

```
$('li:gt(3)').hide();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TEfz9/

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for teaching me about the `gt()` selector in jQuery! Though the use of jQuery seems overkill for this use case unless old browser support is required or if the number is dynamic.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's clearly correct and has a working fiddle. Question was also tagged as jQuery.